# Computing $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\left(-1+\frac1{2n}\right)^k$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}\left(-1+\frac1{2n+1}\right)^k $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $s_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(-1+\frac1{n}\right)^k.$ Heuristically, one conjectures $$s_{2n} -s_{2n-1}\to e^{-1}$$ and $$s_{2n+1}-s_{2n}\to-e^{-1},$$ combining which we would derive the convergence of $s_{2n}$ and $s_{2n+1}$. In fact, $s_{2n}+s_{2n+1}\to1$ *should* (and seems to) hold as well, giving $\lim s_{2n}=\frac12(1+1/e), \lim s_{2n+1}=\frac12(1-1/e),$ apparently true numerically.

However, the above is not rigorous. How can the steps be derived? What is a different (perhaps more general) approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
s_{n} &= \sum_{k = 0}^{n}\left(\frac{1 - n}{n}\right)^{k}\notag\\
&= \dfrac{1 - \left(\dfrac{1 - n}{n}\right)^{n + 1}}{1 - \dfrac{1 - n}{n}}\text{ (sum of a finite GP)}\notag\\
&= \frac{n^{n + 1} - (1 - n)^{n + 1}}{(2n - 1)n^{n}}\notag\\
&= \frac{n}{2n - 1} + (-1)^{n}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n + 1}\frac{n}{2n - 1}
\end{align}
It is now easy to see that $s_{2n} \to 1/2 + 1/2e$ and $s_{2n + 1} \to 1/2 - 1/2e$ because $n/(2n - 1) \to 1/2$ and $(1 - 1/n)^{n + 1} \to 1/e$ as $n \to \infty$. It is also clear from the above that $s_{n}$ does not tend to a limit as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Ah, was thinking too hard... Thank you.

Comment: @VincenzoOliva: Don't worry! It happens to everyone of us once in a while that we think too hard even for simple problems.

Comment: I'll keep it in mind. :D Thanks for your kindness, I appreciate it.